# How does C evaluate these programs?

Tags: c, printf

While learning C I arrived at a point where I was evaluating numerical expressions.

```
main()
{
    printf("%d",4*1/2+3/2*1+2+3.2);
}
```

Here I expect the expression to evaluate to 8.2 (following the hierarchy of operators) and since it's being printed as an integer the value printed on the screen should be 8

But what I get is `26214`.
Why does this value get printed on the screen? (It's remains the same no matter how many times I run it).

---

If I however run the following code,

```
main()
{
    int a;
    a=4*1/2+3/2*1+2+3.2;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

I get the expected value `8`.
The only thing that varies between the two cases is I use a int variable in the second case and print that.

Why does this give me the right answer?

---

Since C is quite prehistoric, I would expect someone might have already asked a similar question. I have searched a bit. If someone could point me to such a question that would be great.

---

I would appreciate if someone could supply a better title to this question.

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall`) and all will become clear.

Comment: I have removed the `compiler-error` tag. The compiler is 100% fine, your code is not

Comment: What about you C book or the `printf` documentation and the `%d` conversion type specifier which can be found by the most simple search is unclear?

Comment: If your compiler doesn't warn you about the incorrect format specifier (like *"'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double'"*) or that the correct form is `int main()`, you should adjust the settings (or get a better compiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version invokes undefined behavior. Second one does not.

When one operand is integer and another one is double that integer is converted to double and the expression is evaluated to double. Since you have `3.2` in your expression, it will be evaluated to double finally. Now you have `%d` in format string but passing a double which is undefined behavior since corresponding arguments type in `printf` must match.

In your second example, the expression is evaluated to double as before but since you are assigning it to integer it will be truncated which is a defined behavior and you get the desired result.

Comment: But shouldn't the double be demoted to a integer so that C could print it as it is assigned?

Comment: No, `printf` doesn't have any way to determine that. It entirely depends on the format string to determine the type. That's why it it UB if argument count and/or type doesn't match format string.

Comment: so if the format type doesn't match then C goes bizarre?

Comment: Yes, if they doesn't match then behavior is undefined which means anything may happen. You must not invoke UB in a program.

Comment: what do you mean by a UB?

Comment: @SmarthBansal you tell the the function what you want to print. And you brake the contract

Comment: Undefined behavior. Please Google for it if you are unaware about it.

Comment: @SmarthBansal = if you do know what the undefined behavior is, I advice some a bit of reading

Answer (score 1):

You have the undefined behavior here. Your expression result is double. But printf expects an integer value.

The second example is different because there is the implicit type converison to int. You can "fix" your first expression by explicit cast

```
  printf("%d",(int)(4*1/2+3/2*1+2+3.2));
```

Comment: Think I got it. Thanks